# API Triggered SMS to a Data Extension

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api, ssjs, sms

I'm trying to find a way to trigger SMS using SSJS Script Activity in the Automation Studio. The records are in the Sendable DE - is it technically possible to trigger SMS within SFMC, using API call within SFMC? go through the records and trigger SMS to the numbers in the DE?

Thank you so much!

Comment: @zuzannamj Sorry, what was the answer?

Comment: Here: https://sfmarketing.cloud/2019/12/20/trigger-sms-text-messages-using-server-side-javascript/

Comment: Thank you Zuzanna :)), I was able to trigger SMS from a CloudPage, but looking how to retrieve rows from the Data Extension and send to the numbers on the Data Extension.